# How can i get output like below? using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, split

Here is my column with String 'ORACLE':

```
COL
---
ORACLE
```

I want the following output:

```
O
R
A
C
L
E
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
SELECT SUBSTR ('ORACLE', LEVEL, 1) FROM dual
Connect by level <= length ('ORACLE');
```

Comment: Note, replace `'ORACLE'` with your column name

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
SELECT SUBSTR(COL, LEVEL, 1) x from tablename
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(COL)
```